# jQuery - first line of li elements in ul

Tags: jquery, html-lists, children

Is there a selector in jQuery which refers to only first line of specific children of the main object?
What I'm referring here to is the following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I only want apply a trigger to the first line of li not the ones embedded within them.

Comment: You could use: `$('ul:first').children()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul class="top">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$("ul.top>li")
```

That means only direct child li nodes of the ul

Otherwise if you don't have control of the classes you can use

```
$("ul:first>li")
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's also executing on the embedded ones

Answer (score 0):

The following code will fetch only the li elements that are children of ul not li

```
    $('ul').children('li');
```

in your code I suppose it ll be something like

```
    $('ul li').click(function(){
        if($(this).parents('li')) {      //add extra check
             return;                    //do nothing
        }

    })
```

This is only to give a hint

Comment: But all `li`s are children of `ul` so this matches them all.

Comment: I think because all the elements that get selected contains the children li too, and so that's seems to be problematic. I have updated the post try it.

Comment: @kingjiv children method only selects the direct children, its the find method that dig deeper in the nested levels.

Comment: The children method finds direct children.  `$("ul")` will contain ALL `ul` elements.  Every `li` is the direct child of one of those `ul` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul:first > li").something(); //<--
```